# Best Practices for Distributed Training with PyTorch custom containers (BYOC) in SageMaker

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, containers, amazon-sagemaker, distributed-training

What are the best practices for distributed training with PyTorch custom containers (BYOC) in Amazon Sagemaker? I understand that PyTorch framework supports native distributed training or using the Horovod library for PyTorch.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach on Amazon SageMaker is to use the SageMaker built in Data Parallel and Model Parallel Libraries. When you use the Pytorch Deep Learning container provided by SageMaker, the library is built in and you can follow the below examples to get started with examples.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/distributed-training-notebook-examples.html

If you are bringing your own container, follow the below link to add SageMaker Distributed training support to your container

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/data-parallel-use-api.html#data-parallel-bring-your-own-container

Apart from this SageMaker also natively supports Pytorch DDP within the native Deep Learning Container used in Pytorch Estimator.

https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/sagemaker.pytorch.html